# Two-line Backaddress in Window of Koma-Script letter

Tags: koma-script, letters, scrlttr2

`scrlttr2` doesn't seem to like 'backaddresses' longer than one line. Two-line backadresses with default layout stick out at the top of the 'address window' and have an very large baseline distance.

[image: default backaddress]

I would like to find a configuration that covers one-line and two-line backaddresses built from `fromname` and `fromaddress` because the layout is defined in a LCO-file that is used by different people. To keep the handling simple, defining individual shorter backaddresses is also not an option. One way to deal with two-line backaddresses seems to be `parbox`. That kind of worked (see MWE below). But I wasn't able to get good inter-word-spacing and proper hyphenation going with `parbox` and `raggedright`.

So, im am searching for a solution with proper hyphenation, inter-word-spacing and if possible left aligned.

MWE of my best attempt:

```
\documentclass[backaddress=plain]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% visualize border of address window
\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
\showfields{address}
\setkomafont{field}{\color{blue}}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Mustermann}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Mittelhochdeutsche Allgemeine Versuchsanstalt\\Musterstr. 12\\34567 Musterstadt}


% construct a new backaddress
\makeatletter
\@setplength{backaddrheight}{18pt}

\setkomavar{backaddress}{\parbox[c]{\useplength{toaddrwidth}}{%
{%\raggedright%     <- (1) has no effect
\def\\{\usekomavar{backaddressseparator}\@ogobble}%
%\raggedright%      <- (2) breaks replacment of \\ with separator
\usekomavar{fromname}\usekomavar{backaddressseparator}\usekomavar{fromaddress}}%
\raggedright%       <- (3) prevents hyphenation but is left aligned 
}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Dr. Moritz Busch\\Georgengarten\\30167 Hannover}
\opening{Mein lieber Freund,}
\blindtext[1]
\closing{Bis bald,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Image of MWE with `raggedright` in position 1 and 2:
[image: backaddress 1 and 2]

Image of MWE with `raggedright` in position 3:

[image: backaddress 3]

Comment: I would never use (automatic) hyphenation in such a backaddress but always format it manually.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You are right, it well never be perfect that way. But in my use case the the users don't have access to the 'lco-' or 'tex-files'. They write markdown which is converted to LaTeX and finally turned into a PDF by pandoc. Its a nice way to create uniform looking letters without alienating TeX-fearing colleagues.

Answer (score 3):

To get a proper hyphenation and left aligned text use simply package `ragged2e` and the command `\RaggedRight` (please note the two capital R).

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[backaddress=plain]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % <===============================================

% visualize border of address window
\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
\showfields{address}
\setkomafont{field}{\color{blue}}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Mustermann}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Mittelhochdeutsche Allgemeine Versuchsanstalt\\Musterstr. 12\\34567 Musterstadt}


% construct a new backaddress
\makeatletter
\@setplength{backaddrheight}{18pt}

\setkomavar{backaddress}{\parbox[c]{\useplength{toaddrwidth}}{%
{%\raggedright%     <- (1) has no effect
\def\\{\usekomavar{backaddressseparator}\@ogobble}%
%\raggedright%      <- (2) breaks replacment of \\ with separator
\usekomavar{fromname}\usekomavar{backaddressseparator}\usekomavar{fromaddress}}%
\RaggedRight%       <- (3) prevents hyphenation but is left aligned <================
}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Dr. Moritz Busch\\Georgengarten\\30167 Hannover}
\opening{Mein lieber Freund,}
\blindtext[1]
\closing{Bis bald,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image: wished result]

Comment: This is along the lines I was searching. Thank you for reminding me of the ragged2e package.

Answer (score 3):

I would redefine `backaddressseparator` to allow a break after the `,`:

```latex
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{,\ }
```

Then you could use

```latex
\documentclass[backaddress=plain]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% visualize border of address window
\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
\showfields{address}
\setkomafont{field}{\color{blue}}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Mustermann}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Mittelhochdeutsche Allgemeine Versuchsanstalt\\Musterstr. 12\\34567 Musterstadt}

% construct a new backaddress
\setplength{backaddrheight}{18pt}% 
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{,\ }
\setkomavar{backaddress}{%
  {\usekomavar{fromname}\usekomavar{backaddressseparator}\usekomavar{fromaddress}\par}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Dr. Moritz Busch\\Georgengarten\\30167 Hannover}
\opening{Mein lieber Freund,}
\blindtext[1]
\closing{Bis bald,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```latex
\documentclass[backaddress=plain]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% visualize border of address window
\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
\showfields{address}
\setkomafont{field}{\color{blue}}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Mustermann}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Mittelhochdeutsche Allgemeine Versuchsanstalt\\Musterstr. 12\\34567 Musterstadt}

% construct a new backaddress
\setplength{backaddrheight}{18pt}
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{,\ }
\makeatletter
\setkomavar{backaddress}{\parbox[c]{\useplength{toaddrwidth}}{%
  \def\\{\usekomavar{backaddressseparator}\@ogobble}%
  \usekomavar{fromname}\usekomavar{backaddressseparator}\usekomavar{fromaddress}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Dr. Moritz Busch\\Georgengarten\\30167 Hannover}
\opening{Mein lieber Freund,}
\blindtext[1]
\closing{Bis bald,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I would define a new variable `shortfromaddress`:

```latex
\documentclass[backaddress=plain]{scrlttr2}
%\providecommand*{\Ifkomavarempty}{\ifkomavarempty}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
\usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% visualize border of address window
\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
\showfields{address}
\setkomafont{field}{\color{blue}}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Mustermann}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Mittelhochdeutsche Allgemeine Versuchsanstalt\\Musterstr. 12\\34567 Musterstadt}

% construct a new backaddress
\newkomavar{shortfromaddress}
\setkomavar{backaddress}{%
  \usekomavar{fromname}\usekomavar{backaddressseparator}
  \Ifkomavarempty{shortfromaddress}%
    {\usekomavar{fromaddress}}
    {\usekomavar{shortfromaddress}}%
}


\setkomavar{shortfromaddress}{MAV\\Musterstr. 12\\34567 Musterstadt}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Dr. Moritz Busch\\Georgengarten\\30167 Hannover}
\opening{Mein lieber Freund,}
\blindtext[1]
\closing{Bis bald,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The breakable backaddressseparator is a very cool idea. Will definitely test it. I hesitate to offer backaddress customization because the users do not interact with the tex-files (see comment below question) but it would be an option to offer shortfromaddress as an additional variabel to the users.

Comment: minor glitch: \Ifkomavarempty{} in the last example needs a lowercase i

Comment: No, `\Ifkomavarempty{}` is correct since KOMA-Script version 3.28, see https://komascript.de/node/2337. If you use version 3.27 or older (current is 3.30) add `\providecommand*{\Ifkomavarempty}{\ifkomavarempty}`.

Comment: ahh, sorry. Didn't expect this to change. I just checked and my KomaScript is quite old (3.24 default in ubuntu 18.04).